# Is there a more readable way to convert types in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries one with the values as strings and one with the types I want to convert to.

```
values = {
    "foreground": {
        "enabled": "True",
        "size": "720",
    },
    "background": {
        "type": "Solid",
        "blur": "True",
        "blur_strength": "15.0",
    }
}

types = {
    "foreground": {
        "enabled": bool,
        "size": int,
    },
    "background": {
        "type": str,
        "blur": bool,
        "blur_strength": float,
    }
}
```

We can  assume that the string in `values` will convert to the corresponding type without raising an exception

Here is my current solution:

```
def correct_types(types: dict, values: dict) -> dict:
    output = {}
    for section, section_dict in values.items():
        output[section] = {}
        for setting, value in section_dict.items():
            output[section][setting] = types[section][setting](value)

    return output
```

It works fine but I feel there is probably a better way to do this that is easier to follow.

Comment: Looks good in my eyes.

Comment: Your code is readable and easy to understand.

Comment: I have added a `dict comprehension` based solution, if that can be considered more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is already in good shape.

Not sure about readability but I always find list comprehensions (dict comprehension in this case) to be a compact way of writing any such logic.

Try this -

```
{i:{k:types[i][k](v) for k,v in values[i].items()} for i in types.keys()}

##### OR #####

{i:{k:types.get(i).get(k)(v) for k,v in values.get(i).items()} for i in types.keys()}
```

```
{'foreground': {'enabled': True, 'size': 720},
 'background': {'type': 'Solid', 'blur': True, 'blur_strength': 15.0}}
```

The `types[i][k]()` OR `types.get(i).get(k)()` is the type class convertor such as `int()` or `bool()` where, `i` is for defining the first level of keys, and `k` is for the second level of keys.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive approach to handle more generic cases:

```py
def parse_dict(d1, d2):
    parsed_dict = {}
    for k1, v1 in d1.items():
        v2 = d2[k1]
        parsed_dict[k1] = v2(v1) if isinstance(v2, type) else parse_dict(v1, v2)
    return parsed_dict

print(parse_dict(values, types))
```

This outputs

```
{'background': {'blur': True, 'blur_strength': 15.0, 'type': 'Solid'},
 'foreground': {'enabled': True, 'size': 720}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a dictionary comprehension:

```
output = {
    # Create an inner dict with a comprehension. k0 is a key from values. k1 is
    # a key from the inner dict.
    k0: {
        # Get the constructor from types.
        k1: types[k0][k1](value)
        # Iterate through an inner dict.
        for k1, value in ground.items()
    }
    # Iterate through the outer dict.
    for k0, ground in values.items()
}
```